# Variable with Offset function to create a range

Tags: vba, excel, variables, offset

I am trying to use a variable alongside the offset function to create a range which I can then utilise.

I have the below code however this errors on the last line.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim targetrow As Range
targetrow = ActiveSheet.Range("Total").Offset(-2, 0).Row
rng = Range(Cells((targetrow), 7), Cells(10, 7))
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Set` with object variables:

```
Set rng = Range(Cells((targetrow), 7), Cells(10, 7))
```

Comment: And you need to declare `targetrow` as `Long` instead of `Range`